# laravel 4 cannot get into the specify controller method

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-4

1. My routes.php

   ```
   Route::get('course/{id}', 'CourseController@show');

   Route::get('course/{id}/{comment_type}', 'CourseController@show');

   Route::get('course/search/{key_word}', 'CourseController@search');
   ```
2. My CourseController.php has these methods

   ```
   public function show($id,$comment_type=1)
   {
     //do something
   }

   public function search($key_word)
   {
    //do something
   }
   ```
3. I want to go into the `search` method. But everytime I invoke

   ```
   course/search/{key_word} //search method in CourseCOntroller
   ```

   It goes into

   ```
   course/{id}/{comment_type} //show method in CourseCOntroller
   ```
4. I debug source code. And I found out that the `UrlMatcher` has a `matchCollection` function, and I found the reason, laravel generates a wrong `Regular Expression`
   When I invoke `course/search/{key_word}`, it generates a regular expression like this?

   ```
   #^/course/(?P<id>[^/]++)/(?P<comment_type>[^/]++)$#s
   ```
5. I don't know how this regular expressions produce.
6. How can I fix the problem, that it calls the `search` method when I invoke  `course/search/{key_word}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alter the sequence of your routes:

```
<?php
Route::get('course/search/{key_word}', 'CourseController@search');
Route::get('course/{id}/{comment_type}', 'CourseController@show');
Route::get('course/{id}', 'CourseController@show');
```

Because {id} is an wildcard, it will pick up every route.

See http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-parameters -> 'Regular Expression Route Constraints'
or Route model binding @ http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-model-binding

Comment: Well, it is. with ->where() on custom routebindings you can twist it every way you like ;)